# How to update react state that has object?

Tags: reactjs

I have state in react that includes object called increment. Inside that object i have a property called count with a value of 0.
Does anyone know how to increment count value with a button click?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      increment:{
        count:0
      }
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }


  handleClick() {

    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        increment.count: prevState.increment.count + 1
      }
    })
  } 


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <h1>{this.state.increment.count}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change!</button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

React gives me error called Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax of updating state is wrong. you can't add key as increment.count. Here is correct syntax.

```
handleClick() {

    this.setState(prevState => {
       return {
           increment: {
               count: prevState.increment.count + 1
           }
       }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        increment: {
            count: prevState.increment.count + 1
        },
    })
}
```